# Error en query join laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql

hola tengo un problema al hacer la consulta en mi programa quiero unir 2 tablas a join

este es el codigo

```
$preguntas=DB::table('preguntas')
->join('empleados', 'empleados.id', '=' ,'preguntas.id')
->select('preguntas.Pregunta','preguntas.Opcion1','empleados.Rut','empleados.nombre')
->get();

dd($preguntas);
```

en todos los ejemplos que vi en el join le agregaban al algo extra despues del id, si lo dejo asi no se muestra los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto fotos de la base datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si estás usando Laravel no hay necesidad de usar las consultas así, dime tienes los modelos de esas tablas creadas? por que con las relaciones de eloquent eso queda mas simple

Comment: De paso agrega por favor tus tablas para comprender mejor la consulta que buscas lograr

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener este formato primero `SELECT`, después el `JOIN` y la tabla que vas a relacionar debes preguntar primero `preguntas.id = empleados.id`, no al revés.

Te quedaría así:

```
$preguntas=DB::table('preguntas')
->select('preguntas.Pregunta','preguntas.Opcion1','empleados.Rut','empleados.nombre')
->join('empleados', 'preguntas.id', '=' ,'empleados.id')
->get();

dd($preguntas);
```

**EDITO:**

Para que tu tabla sea de acorde a una relación como tal debe quedar relacionado el `cargo_id` de la tabla pregunta con el `id` del empleado y cambiar el `JOIN` por esto:

```
->join('empleados', 'preguntas.cargo_id', '=' ,'empleados.id')
```

Comment: La igualación que se hace en el `ON` que son los valores que mencionas no afectan en que orden estén

Comment: Seguro? Eso independiente si ocupa Sql Server?

Comment: totalmente no afecta, de todos modos si estamos hablando de un join, ¿no debería buscar la igualdad entre llave primaria y llave foránea? y no como ahorita que parecen ambas primarias

Comment: Ahora que me percato lo que quiere unir no es el `id` de ambos sino el `cargo_id`

Comment: Si, por eso le dejé comentarios pidiendo agregue sus tablas y mas detalles por que no es claro al inicio en lo que trata de hacer

Answer (score 0):

probe el codigo de arriba

```
$preguntas=DB::table('preguntas')
    ->select('preguntas.Pregunta','preguntas.Opcion1','empleados.Rut','empleados.Nombre')
    ->join('empleados', 'preguntas.cargo_id', '=' ,'empleados.id')
    ->get();

    dd($preguntas);
```

ese y me marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla preguntas

```
Schema::create('preguntas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('Pregunta');
    $table->string('Opcion1');
    $table->string('Opcion2');
    $table->string('Opcion3');
    $table->string('Opcion4');
    $table->string('Respuesta');
    //Tipo de pregunta: General para todo tipo de empleado, Especifica para cierto cargo
    $table->string('tipo');
    //Ante pregunta General, cargo id nulo
    $table->string('cargo_id')->nullable(); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
    }
```

tabla empleados

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empleados', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('Rut');
            $table->string('Nombre');
            $table->string('Apellido');
            $table->string('Fecha');
            $table->string('Cargo');
            $table->string('Foto');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

otra cosa las tablas que quiero unir es una relacion muchos a muchos pero no creo que afecte

tabla empleados_preguntas

```
Schema::create('empleado_pregunta', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->bigInteger('empleado_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('pregunta_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('empleado_id')->references('id')->on('empleados')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');


            $table->foreign('pregunta_id')->references('id')->on('preguntas')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');

        });
    }
```

Comment: Si tu relación es de muchos a muchos, entonces hace falta agregues la tercer tabla, además el join ya no sería como lo pones, por eso es necesario nos digas si tienes los modelos creados

Comment: como seria el join con la tabla de quiebre?

Comment: antes aclarame por favor que información tratas de obtener?, es decir ¿cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: necesito sacar la informacion de la tabla preguntas y mostrarla en una vista.por ejemplo tengo 5 preguntas se las tengo que asignar esas 5 preguntas a un empleado por eso la relacion muchos a muchos.

Comment: Entonces @DiegoFuentes: ¿Ocupas obtener al usuario que ingresa al sistema, tener esas 5 preguntas y asignarselas para registrar esos 5 valores en la tabla muchos a muchos cierto?

Comment: si eso mismo, eso quiero hacer